# Efficiently calculate the difference between two rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a dataframe as below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['f1', 'f2'], index=['r1', 'r2'])
>>> df
    f1  f2
r1   1   2
r2   3   4
```

How should I efficiently calculate the absolute different between row `r1` and `r2` and create another row as `r3` to keep the result. That is to say the result will look like:

```
>>> for cn in df.columns:
...     diff_dat.append(abs(df[cn]['r1'] - df[cn]['r2']))
... 
>>> diff_dat
[2, 2]
>>> df.append(pd.DataFrame([diff_dat], index=['r3'], columns=df.columns))
    f1  f2
r1   1   2
r2   3   4
r3   2   2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select rows, subtract, get [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) and last add new row by [`setting with enlargement`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc['r3'] = (df.loc['r1'] - df.loc['r2']).abs()
print (df)
    f1  f2
r1   1   2
r2   3   4
r3   2   2
```

Performance for 1000 columns:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 1000)), index=['r1', 'r2']).add_prefix('f')-5

#Mayank Porwal solution
In [40]: %timeit df.append(df.diff().dropna().abs())
1.51 ms ± 19.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#jezrael solution
In [41]: %timeit df.loc['r3'] = (df.loc['r1'] - df.loc['r2']).abs()
663 µs ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#NaT3z solution
In [42]: %timeit df.loc["r3"] = df.apply(lambda c: abs(c["r1"] - c["r2"]), axis=0)
967 µs ± 80.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For improve performance is possible use `numpy`:

```
In [49]: %timeit df.loc['r3'] = np.abs(df.loc['r1'].values - df.loc['r2'].values)
414 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @anky_91 - Op need select by rows with names, so here `loc` is necessary.

Comment: Useful and straight forward with example easy to understand. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
In [576]: df.append(df.diff().dropna().abs())
Out[583]: 
     f1   f2
r1  1.0  2.0
r2  3.0  4.0
r2  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: This is a neat solution among all feedback I have seen so far. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution for this is to use the .loc function which takes row indexes.

*(Edited to remove code identical to that written by jezrael)*

If you aren't familiar with pandas I'd suggest checking out the DataFrame.apply function since it allows broader manipulations of data (both row-wise and columns-wise). A solution would look like this:

```
df["r3"] = df.apply(lambda c: abs(c["r1"] - c["r2"]), axis=0)
```

pandas.DataFrame.apply is a powerful tool, letting you apply functions to the rows or columns in your dataset and taking advantage of pandas vectorisation.

Comment: Very useful and I do need to bite the document of pandas. Many thanks for the sharing.